# Windows 10, Volume does not change unless audio is playing

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headset

I am using a sony bluetooth headset and when I press the buttons on the headset to increase or decrease the volume. It does not change unless there is audio playing on my PC.
How can I change it so that it changes the volume even when there is no audio actively playing?

It does not have this issue on my android phone.

When the audio does change, the floating popup appears:

[image]

Edit: It also does not have this issue when I use the volume buttons on my keyboard. Only on the bluetooth headset.

Comment: Which headset model? Have you checked for firmware updates

Comment: @harrymc Sony MDRXB950BT/B Extra Bass Bluetooth Headphones. Don't know of any updates.

Comment: Indeed, there are no [downloads](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/product/mdr-xb950bt/downloads) from Sony. If the problem is with the generic PC driver, it might not have a solution.